# Cardinality of a Quotient Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Let $X = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10\}$ and $P=\{2,3,5,7\}$. In $P(X)$ define the equivalence $A\mathcal{R}B$ if $A\setminus P = B \setminus P$ . Then what is the cardinal of the quotient set? I noted that the equivalence class of $\{\}$ is $P(\{2,3,5,7\})$ - the sets containing no elements not in $P$ - and I conjecture that the cardinality of the quotient set is $2^6$, but am unsure of how to prove it.

Comment: What did you try, other than writing the question here?

Comment: Not so, I tested before making the question. I tried to calculate the equivalence class of $ 0 $, I know that the equivalence class $0$ items belong 2,3,5,7 and all elements of $P({2,3,5,7})$.
I have deduced that the value of the cardinal could be 2⁶ but I preferred to ask because I do not know if it's true and I would like to demonstrate theoretically.

Comment: @Blunt I edited your comment into your question - it's better to include your attempts directly in the question. (And I hope my edit is faithful to your intent, but you can feel free to fix it if it is not)

Comment: Thanks. I'll remember it for next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't care anymore about 4 elements, so only 6 remaining. That's why the cardinality of your quotient should be
$$2^6=64.$$

If you want to prove it formally show that $\overline{A}\mapsto A\setminus P$ is a bijection between the quotient $Q$ and $P(X\setminus P)$. Hence we have
$$|Q|=|P(X\setminus P)|=2^{|X\setminus P|}=2^6=64.$$